# useEffect always has empty array on refresh

Tags: reactjs, next.js

If I navigate the website using the navigation it works fine but if I refresh the browser then what I get from useEffect is always an empty array but I don't know why.

```
  const [footerSidebars, setFooterSidebars] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const ourRequest = axios.CancelToken.source();
    const getFooter = async () => {
      async function getSidebarOne() {
        try {
          const { data } = await axios.get(
            `http://localhost:8888/example/wp-json/api-sidebars/v1/sidebar1`
          );
          return data;
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }

      async function getSidebarTwo() {
        try {
          const { data } = await axios.get(
            `http://localhost:8888/example/wp-json/api-sidebars/v1/sidebar3`
          );
          return data;
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }

      const sidebars = await axios.all([getSidebarOne(), getSidebarTwo()]);

      setFooterSidebars(sidebars);

      console.log(footerSidebars);
    };
    getFooter();
    return () => {
      ourRequest.cancel();
    };
  }, []);
```

I get an undefined error when trying to output the data

```
    {footerSidebars && (
      <div
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(footerSidebars[0].body_response),
        }}
      />
    )}
```

UPDATE:

I added a length check and it seems to work now. Is this the correct approach though?

```
    {footerSidebars.length && (
      <div
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(footerSidebars[0].body_response),
        }}
      />
    )}
```

Comment: You might not be doing it wrong, it's just that when you log `footerSidebars`, the variable will be set in the next render cycle because you just set it right above it. if you put your `console.log` outside the useEffect, you'll see it has the value when the component re-renders.

Comment: Ah, I see. It logs to console twice. First is an empty array and then it has the data. That solves that. Now when I actually try output the data I get 'cannot read property body_response of undefined' I will update my question with the code

Comment: `footerSidebars.length && ...` or `footerSidebars[0] && ...`

Comment: @choz it is no longer undefined since I did the .length check

Comment: Yep, I just noticed Giovanni approach after I commented. Looking good!

Comment: Thanks to all for your assistance!

Comment: @Waterfall You may want to add the solution you found as an answer to your own question. This clearly indicates the question already has an answer.